# How to implement a logic which involves multiple search criteria

Tags: logic

I am not sure whether I can ask such kind of questions here. Apologizes if this is an improper question.

We have a functionality which searches some items based on the user input. The problem is the user can enter multiple criteria. The possible combinations are

1. name:some name
2. type:some type
3. domain: some domain
4. name:some name [ & | ] domain:some domain
5. name:some name [ & | ] type:some type
6. type:some type [ & | ] domain:some domain
7. name:some name [ & | ] type:some type [ & | ] domain:some domain

The 'domain' and 'type' are attributes of type X and 'name' is an attribute of type Y.

I have implemented different methods which actually retrieves all data for different combinations. The basic methods are

```
Set<Item> getItemsForAName(String name)
Set<Item> getItemsForADomain(String domain)
Set<Item> getItemsForAType(String type)
```

Other methods will use these 3 methods internally and will return the result.

The problem I am facing is now I have to write some logic which will actually call appropriate method based on the search string.

After various logics finally I decided to use regular expressions. So I wrote some if else statements like this

```
//I have the search string separated and put in a map already
if(searchString.matches("name:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<item> items = getItemsForAName(map.get("name"));
} else if (searchString.matches("type:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForAType(map.get("type"));
} else if (searchString.matches("domain:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForAType(map.get("domain"));
} else if (searchString.matches("domain:[\\w\\s-]+&type:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForADomainAndType(map.get("domain"), map.get("type"));
} else if (searchString.matches("domain:[\\w\\s-]+&name:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForADomainAndName(map.get("domain"), map.get("name"));
} else if (searchString.matches("type:[\\w\\s-]+&name:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForATypeAndName(map.get("type"), map.get("name"));
} else if (searchString.matches("domain:[\\w\\s-]+\\|type:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForADomainOrType(map.get("domain"), map.get("type"));
} else if (searchString.matches("domain:[\\w\\s-]+\\|name:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForADomainOrName(map.get("domain"), map.get("name"));
} else if (searchString.matches("type:[\\w\\s-]+\\|name:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForATypeOrName(map.get("type"), map.get("name"));
} else if (searchString.matches("domain:[\\w\\s-]+&type:[\\w\\s-]+&name:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForADomainAndTypeAndName(map.get("domain"), map.get("type"), map.get("name"));
} else if (searchString.matches("domain:[\\w\\s-]+\\|type:[\\w\\s-]+\\|name:[\\w\\s-]+")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForADomainOrTypeOrName(map.get("domain"), map.get("type"), map.get("name"));
}
```

I suppose that this is a stupid logic. I have even tried some other ways to break this logic. Other logic I wrote is while constructing the map I store the separators even. I use a LinkedHashMap for this because I need the insertion order to make it a bit simple. Then I write some if else statements like this

```
if(!map.get("name").isEmpty() && !map.get("type").isEmpty() &&  map.get("domain").isEmpty() && !map.get("separator1").equals("&") &&  map.get("separator2").equals("&")) {
    Set<Item> items = getItemsForADomainAndTypeAndName(map.get("domain"), ap.get("type"), map.get("name"));
} else if .....
```

However I dint choose the second procedure because I need the insertion order I am using LinkedHashMap so may become a problem in future and I need to even put the separators in the map. So I decided to go with RegEx way. The problem is regular expressions take more time I read somewhere. I am not able to take a decision or I am not sure whether there is an even better approach.

Can anyone please suggest a simple solution? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using an overloaded search function (if your language supports this) that will call the appropriate function based on an if/else ladder that checks whether certain values are not null.